# jQuery change toggle into display block and display none

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use the following code to toggle between display block and display inline for a specific element. But we do not want to apply the style display inline, we want to change it between display block and display none.

How can we achieve this?

jQuery;

```
require(["jquery"], function (e) {
    const t = function () {
        const t = e("#togglebtw").is(":checked");
        e(".price-container .price-including-tax").toggle(!t), 
        e(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").toggle(t), 
        localStorage.setItem("togglebtw", t ? "true" : "false");
    };
    e(function () {
        e("#togglebtw")
            .on("click", t)
            .prop("checked", "true" === localStorage.getItem("togglebtw")),
            t();
    });
});
```

Comment: In that case you need to style the element as display block to begin with.  https://api.jquery.com/toggle/  The API explicitly talks about if an element is stylized as inline or not, and how the behavior changes.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! But that's the main problem in there, we need the hide the element that onload is display none. So wee need to change the jQuery and change it from display none to block.

Comment: How are you changing it to display none on page load?  I guess that is the `e()` part?

Comment: @Taplar Yes we use therefore the `e()` part.

Comment: So that part is just applying the inline style of display none on it on load.  And then when it gets toggled again, the inline style is removed, and it reverts to whatever display property it inheriently has.  If you don't want the inherient style to apply, you have to change it.  Here is an example with a span, who is inheriently not display block.  https://jsfiddle.net/qr621hmL/

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, but that's the main problem here. We need to give this element the styling display: none; because of lazy load JS. It works fine until we give the element the display none in css. Then when toggling it changes to display inline.